# Android Studio Build Process won't completely delete view in xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle, android-databinding

I am deleting an element in an xml layout file, that has an error.

Every time I clean and/or clean/build, the element keeps popping back
into the xml file.

As if, I hadn't deleted it.

Android Studio has auto save but I hit save every time I delete the element.

I even delete all the directories under build/intermediates.

What gives with Android Studio?

```
   /Users/Shared/xxxx/code/xxxx/app/build/intermediates/
    data-binding-layout-out/tol/debug/layout/activity_xxxx.xml
   Error:(399) No resource identifier found for attribute 'letter_typeface' in package 'com.xxxxx.xxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the build process will regenerate the files under the debug directory. Either you can fix the relevant issues on attributes in the file under your res/layout directory or you can delete your .xml file from the previously mentioned directory.